# Change font style from SQL value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's the thing:

Let's say that I'm creating a database for a football season. There are two columns: player1 and player 2, and a third one wich I will call it "flag".
What I need is that if the flag is on "1", the text for the player1 change to bold and the player2 remain normal or viceversa if the flag is 2.

I know it sounds difficult, but that's the best way to put it. The real case is harder to explain.

Cheers!

Comment: `if (flag == 1) { showBold }`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is:

```
$results = [
    array(
        'team1' => 'TEAM_1',
        'team2' => 'TEAM_2',
        'flag' => 0,
    ),
    array(
        'team1' => 'TEAM_1',
        'team2' => 'TEAM_2',
        'flag' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'team1' => 'TEAM_1',
        'team2' => 'TEAM_2',
        'flag' => 2,
    ),
];
foreach ($results as $r) {
    if ($r['flag'] == 1) {
        echo '<b>' . $r['team1'] . '</b>';
    } else {
        echo $r['team1'];
    }
    echo ' vs. ';
    if ($r['flag'] == 2) {
        echo '<b>' . $r['team2'] . '</b>';
    } else {
        echo $r['team2'];
    }
}
```